# Java QueryDsl for "update myTable where myColumn in ('interesting', 'values')"?

Tags: java, querydsl

I'm trying to translate this query in QueryDsl:

```
update myThings set firstColumn = 'newValue' where secondColumn in ('interesting', 'stuff')
```

I spent hours looking for documentation but the java fu is just not strong enough in this one... :( I can find all kinds of QueryDsl example, but I cant find any for this. I will probably need SimpleExpression.eqAny(CollectionExpression), but I can't figure out how to build such a CollectionExpression around my simple list of strings.

```
List<String> interestingValues = Arrays.asList("interesting", "stuff");

queryFactory.update(myThings)
    .set(myThings.firstColumn, "newValue")
//  .where(myThings.secondColumn.in(interestingValues)
//         'in' will probably try to look in table "interestingValues"?
//  .where(myThings.secondColumn.eqAny(interestingValues)
//         'eqAny' seems interesting, but doesn't accept a list
    .execute();
```

All I can find is API definitions, but then I get lost in generics any other "new" java concepts which I still have trouble understanding. An example would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use `new JPAUpdateClause(session, myThings)`:

```
JPAUpdateClause<myThings> update = new JPAUpdateClause(session, myThings);
update.set(myThings.firstColumn, "newValue")
      .where(myThings.secondColumn.in(interestingValues))
      .execute();
```

If you are using hibernate, use `HibernateUpdateClause()` instead;

Comment: That's what I tried, but I get:

DEBUG main [o.h.SQL] update myThings set firstColumn=? where secondColumn=?
(...)
WARN  main [o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper] SQL Warning Code: -1100, SQLState: 02000
2015-12-13 06:43:47,337 WARN  main [o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper] no data

... but I expect:
DEBUG main [o.h.SQL] update myThings set firstColumn=? where (secondColumn in (?))

Comment: secondColumn=? is converted to in (?) automatically by the implementation. Don't look into the DEBUG logs, look the results you get instead.

Comment: Yay, I got it to work! Turns out that apparently Amazon Redshift considers a null to be equal to any string, this threw me off. Thanks!